# PowerShell using variables to create adb push command

Tags: powershell, adb

I'm trying to import file names and paths from a csv file to create individual adb push commands to push files to an Android device with the following script.

```
adb push "$($c.DirectoryName)\$($c.Name) $targetPath"

Write-Host adb push "$($c.DirectoryName)\$($c.Name) $targetPath"
```

The output of Write-Host gives me `adb push C:\temp\Files\test.jpg /sdcard` which works as a command if I copy and paste into PowerShell but my script does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just got the quotation wrong. In general, only quote single argument string *literals*. If an argument is a single variable, then don't quote it because PowerShell already does the quoting, if necessary.

Try this:

```sh
adb push "$($c.DirectoryName)\$($c.Name)" $targetPath
```

Actually you could just use the `Fullname` property so you don't need any quoting at all:

```sh
adb push $c.Fullname $targetPath
```

In your original code you passed `"$($c.DirectoryName)\$($c.Name) $targetPath"` as a single argument, due to the quoting, although the string actually contains multiple arguments.